# Saving Parse.com objects into Trigger.io prefs storage is stripping data from object?

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as my backend for a Trigger.io based Android app. My problem is pretty basic, and I'm convinced it's just some fundamental understanding of javascript that I'm not grasping - I'm still learning a lot about the language.

When I query Parse for an array of objects, and log the response, I get everything I need: the attributes, the unique object id, createdAt, updatedAt, etc for each object. Here is an example of a single object from Parse:

### Object from Parse:

```
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   : [FORGE] 
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   : [ { attributes: 
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :      { first_name: 'John',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        last_name: 'Smith',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        email: 'john.smith@aol.com',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        phone: '5551112234',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        address: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        city: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        state: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        zip: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        race: '7',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        theDate: '10/02/2012',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        formName: 'DriverWaiver',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        imported: true },
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _operations: {},
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _dirty: {},
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _hashedJSON: {},
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _escapedAttributes: {},
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     cid: 'c38',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     id: 'beLlUqrUBl',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     createdAt: '2012-10-02T17:51:38.267Z',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     updatedAt: '2012-10-02T17:51:38.267Z',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _setting: false,
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :     _previousAttributes: 
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :      { first_name: 'John',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        last_name: 'Smith',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        email: 'john.smith@aol.com',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        phone: '5551112234',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        address: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        city: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        state: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        zip: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        race: '7',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        theDate: '10/02/2012',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        formName: 'DriverWaiver',
    [INFO] 10-03 10:34:21.992 18060 18072 I Forge   :        imported: true } },
```

However after saving the result, with no variable manipulation, using Trigger.io's forge.prefs.set(), I'm only able to read the attributes. Here is the same object after reading using forge.prefs.get():

### After saving with forge.prefs.set() and retrieving with forge.prefs.get():

```
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   : [FORGE] 
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   : [ { first_name: 'John',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     last_name: 'Smith',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     email: 'john.smith@aol.com',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     phone: '5551112233',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     address: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     city: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     state: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     zip: '',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     race: '7',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     theDate: '10/02/2012',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     formName: 'DriverWaiver',
    [INFO] 10-03 11:05:44.594 19055 19068 I Forge   :     imported: true },
```

### Simplified code to produce above results

```
    var FormData = Parse.Object.extend(formName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(FormData);
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    query.endsWith("theDate", currentYear.toString());
    query.limit(1000);
    query.descending('imported');

    // get from parse
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {

        // got from Parse
        if (formName == "DriverWaiver") forgeLog(results);

        // save to local
        forge.prefs.set(formName, results, function(){

            // saved to local
            forgeLog("Saved to Local");

                // get from local
                forge.prefs.get(formName, function(results){

                    // got from local
                    forgeLog("Got from Local");
                    if (formName == "DriverWaiver") forgeLog(results);      

                }, function(){

                    // error getting from local
                    forgeLog("Error getting from Local");

                });         

        }, function (){ 
            // error saving to local
            forgeLog("Error saving to Local");
        });
      },
      error: function(error) { 
          // error getting from parse
          forgeLog("Error getting data from Parse");

      }
    });
```

So I guess my question is: **how am I able to save the entire object?** I really need that unique id saved for my app to function correctly.

I sent full logging output to Trigger support, and they've concluded it's a Parse API issue and deferred me to them. I'm not convinced it's a Parse issue, but instead of bouncing around to support channels I'm hoping the community here could provide some insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've created a little demo app which stores and retrieves the logged object in the prefs module: https://github.com/goodgravy/forge-spikes/tree/master/prefs-demo - the object's identical after retrieval. In your code, is the "results" returned from the Parse query a plain-old JSON-y object? If it's not, I'd recommend serialising it to one before storing it. Also, if you can send a runnable app to us at support@trigger.io we'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Thanks James, appreciate your help over these past few months :) Will take a look at this app and do some more testing.